# Is there a way to create a group that minimizes duplication based on history?

Tags: algorithm

I need to make groups on a regular basis.
But I'd like to minimize duplicates based on history.

If there are 6 people A to F, the groups could be

```
"AB", "CD", "EF"
```

and next time

```
"AC", "BE", "DF"
```

```
"AD", "BF", "CF"
```

...

I know I can't avoid duplication eventually, but I'd liked to minimize it.
I found it cumbersome to form a group of 10 people out of 100.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: First, make groups ```[1,2,3,...,9,10], [11,12,13,...,19,20], .... [91,92,...,99,100]```. Then, switch the last numbers clockwise, to give```[1,2,3,...9,20], [11,12,...19,30],...[91,92...,99,10]```. When this cycle gets completed, start swapping the second last numbers and so on

Answer (score 0):

If the values wouldn't be so big (100 and 100), I would simply generate all
nCr(100,10) = 17310309456440 possibilities, store them and than take one of them by random until all are consumed.
Because of the high number in your case this seams to be not feasible.

So I would go for an approach like the one you already sketched out.
Make a List of all groups and count how often they already appeared.

Than generate groups by random (e.g. 10 times) and take the one where the groups occurred the less in the past.